# Is this Comic sans MS?

Tags: font-identification

Could somebody tell me if this text is written in Comic sans MS?
It looks like that.
It is a quote from a famous Québec premier (René Lévesque) which is engraved on a monument in Québec city, Canada.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/capitalenationale/3797412919/

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's Comic Sans.

You can also check the font using *What The Font* at [MyFonts.com](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is Comic Sans MS Bold.